# Applescript to get track number of song from multi-cd album in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, applescript

I have an Applescript that reports the currently playing song name, album, song number, and total number of songs on the album. If the album comes from a single CD or if the song comes from CD 1 of a multi-CD album, everything works, and I get the following:

```
Song 2 of 30
```

However, if the album comes from a multi-CD set, then the song number is incorrect for songs from CD 2, CD 3, etc. Here's an example: *L'Elisir d'Amore* has two CDs, and in iTunes, it is entered as such (e.g., CD 1 of 2 and CD 2 of 2). The script correctly reports there are 30 songs (16 on CD 1 and 14 on CD 2). When playing a song from CD 1, everything is accurate. When playing a song from CD 2, the song number begins again at 1, so the very last song appears as

```
Song 14 of 30
```

because it is the 14th song on CD 2. Is there a way to get the script to display Song 30 of 30 for the last song on CD 2 without some kludge of figuring out the number of CDs, then counting up the songs in CD 1 and then adding to the track number of the song in CD 2? This kludge gets quite ugly for albums spanning as many as 14 CDs.

Here's the simplified bit of code:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    -- code to check that there is a current song
    set z_album to album of current track as string
    set z_num to count of (every track whose album is z_album)
    set z_song to name of current track as string
    set z_trk to track number of current track
    log z_song & " (" & z_trk & " of  " & z_num & ")"
end tell
```

Comment: It would be nice to know if my kludge worked for you, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which does work, and is less kudgy than mine. This was really just for informational purposes than for any important reason: I have the info displayed and didn't want to repeatedly execute a largish script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I do not have much of a need, if any, to automate iTunes with AppleScript. In the past I've found iTunes to be one of the more difficult apps to automate. Nonetheless, I took a look at your *code*, the AppleScript Dictionary for iTunes, a few web searches that basically yielded nothing noteworthy, and some failed programmatic attempts to *easily* get a *list* of *discs* and `track count` for each *disc* of an `album`.

I'll assume the **kludge** context in your question is because there is *no easy direct way* to programmatically ask an `album` for its `disc count` and `track count` per *disc* to do the *math* with, in a *straight forward manner*. So with that... here's *my* **kludge**, which was tested and works as desired on ***my*** iTunes Library:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    try

        set theCurrentTrackProperties to (properties of current track)

        if (disc number in theCurrentTrackProperties) is not greater than 1 then

            set theSongName to (name in theCurrentTrackProperties)
            set theTrackNumber to (track number in theCurrentTrackProperties)
            set theTrackCount to (track count in theCurrentTrackProperties)

            log theSongName & " (" & theTrackNumber & " of " & theTrackCount & ")"

        else

            set theSongName to (name in theCurrentTrackProperties)
            set theTrackNumber to (track number in theCurrentTrackProperties)
            set theTrackCount to (count of (every track whose album = (album in theCurrentTrackProperties)))

            set theDiscNumber to (disc number in theCurrentTrackProperties)
            set theAlbumsTracksProperties to (properties of every track whose album = (album in theCurrentTrackProperties))

            set theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo to ""
            repeat with i from 1 to (count of theAlbumsTracksProperties)
                tell item i in theAlbumsTracksProperties
                    set theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo to (theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo & disc number & space & track count & linefeed)
                end tell
            end repeat
            tell current application
                set theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo to (do shell script "sort -n -k1 -u <<<" & quoted form of theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo & " | sed '/^$/d'")
                set theTracksPerDiscCount to ""
                repeat with i from 1 to (theDiscNumber - 1)
                    set theTracksPerDiscCount to (theTracksPerDiscCount + (word 2 of paragraph i in theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo))
                end repeat
                set theTrackNumber to (theTrackNumber + theTracksPerDiscCount)
            end tell

            log theSongName & " (" & theTrackNumber & " of " & theTrackCount & ")"

        end if

    on error eStr number eNum
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon caution
        return
    end try
end tell
```

The example AppleScript *code*, shown above, does the following:

- Sets the *properties* of the `current track` to the *variable* `theCurrentTrackProperties`.
- Checks to see if the *value* of the `disc number` *property* in the *variable*, `theCurrentTrackProperties`, is not greater than 1.
- If the *value* of the `disc number` *property* is not greater than 1, it's straight forward processing and logs the desired information.
- If the *value* of the `disc number` *property* is greater than 1, then the `else` *branch* preforms the **kludge** to do the *math*, and logs the desired information.

What the **kludge** does:

- Sets some additional initial *variables*.

  - One for the *value* of the `disc number` *property* of the `current track`,`theDiscNumber`, is used to determine how many *discs* the `track count` is needed for.
  - Another to hold the *properties* of every `track` of every `disc` in the `album`, `theAlbumsTracksProperties`.

    - The *value* of the *variable*, `theAlbumsTracksProperties`, is processed in a `repeat` *loop* to which the *output* of is held in the *variable* `theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo`.
- The *variable* `theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo`, is a *list* of the `disc number` and `track count` from every `track` in the `album`.

  - This *list* is then processed to remove all duplicate info, so as to have a singular entry for the `track count` of each `disc number` in the `album`.
- The `do shell script` *command* uses `sort` and `sed` to process the *list*, the *value* of the *variable* `theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo`.

  - `sort -n -k1 -u <<<`

    - `-n` compare according to string numerical value
    - `-k1` start a key at POS1
    - `-u` without **-c**, output only the first of an equal run
    - `<<<` directs input from the *command line*, not a *file*
  - `theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo` the *list* as *command line input* directed to `sort`
  - `| sed '/^$/d'`

    - `|` pipe the *output* of the `sort` *command* to `sed`
    - `sed '/^$/d'` delete blank lines
    - Because the *value* of the *variable* `theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo` is a concatenation with a `linefeed` at the end of each `repeat` *loop*, it becomes the first line of *output* from the `sort` *command* and is removed with `sed`, so as not to have to account for the leading blank line later in the *script*. If it was left as a part of *value* of the *variable* `theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo`, that's (re)set by the *return* of the `do shell script` *command*, then `word 2 of paragraph i` would have to be `word 2 of paragraph (i + 1)` in order to skip the leading blank line. So it makes more sense to remove it before it ends up as part of the final *value* of the *variable* `theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo`.
- With the *variable*, `theAlbumsDiscNumberTrackCountInfo`, now only containing a *list* of `disk number` with its corresponding `track count`, one line for each *disc* in the `album`, it's now easy to do the *math*, whether the `album` contains 2 *discs* or as many as 14 *discs*, or more.
- The remaining AppleScript *code*, which includes another `repeat` *loop*, preforms the *math* necessary to add up the `track count` of each `disc number` preceding the `disc number` the `current track` is from, and adds them together, and then logs the desired information.

---

That said, if anyone knows an *easy direct way* to programmatically ask an `album` for its `disc count` and `track count` per *disc* to do the *math* with, in a straight forward manner to avoid a **kludge**, please post an answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer, which does work and may be suitable for other purposes. I also really liked the clear explanation! However, I'll continue to reply on reporting Song 12 of Disc 3 of 4 simply to keep the script to only a half-dozen lines.

Comment: @RPW, Thanks. you said, "I'll continue to reply on reporting Song 12 of Disc 3 of 4 simply to keep the script to only a half-dozen lines.", and if I may, why is there and issue with keeping the number of lines of code down?